# Searching Content of any king of Document From Alfresco using OpenCMIS

Tags: java, alfresco, opencmis

Is it necessary to perform indexing on documents of Alfresco while searching the content in any type of document?

Because I am searching the content using OpenCMIS query with IN_FOLDER('ID') as well as IN_TREE('ID'), but I am getting the response only for .TXT file type.

I found null from all file except .TXT. Here is my Code for searching From Folder as well as Tree.

From Folder:

```
String query ="select * from cmis:document where IN_FOLDER('"+ folder.getId() +"') AND CONTAINS('ABC')";
```

From Tree:

```
String query ="select * from cmis:document where IN_TREE('"+folder.getId()+"') AND CONTAINS('ABC')";
```

Comment: If you use Lucene Search from Alfresco, and you search: `ALL:"ABC"` do you obtain the same results?